# ssrs 2008 r2 working abnormally

Tags: reporting-services

I am facing problems in working with Report Manager of SSRS2008R2. It was working properly few days back but now I am not been able to delete or can do anything on report server.

There is a dropdown menu that usually appears when we hovor the mouse on the individual report that perform different operations like delete, rights management etc but now no dropdown appears on the report. I can not delete anything nor does I perform rights management etc nothing.

If anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution by installing the latest browsers.

However I want to still inquire why the Report Server was running very fine with the browsers previously.